# Shrinking semi-transparent overlay on hover

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-shapes

I want to create this effect with CSS3 that exist in this [link](http://www.dnnskin.net/DesktopModules/ArtStore/Templates/ProductDetail/demo-295.html).

In this page, there exist four circular images that have a beautiful and advanced effect. The effect is that of a **semi-transparent overlay on top of the image that moves/shrinks in when the image is hovered**. Initially, the image is transparent (has no overlay) and when the hover transition is complete the image gets the semi-transparent overlay.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are looking for the effect that is displayed while hovering on the circles with image then it can be achieved by using `box-shadow` and a pseudo element like shown in the below snippet.

The pseudo-element has a `box-shadow` with spread radius equal to the size of the container in order to produce the semi transparent overlay on the element. Initially size of the pseudo-element is same as that of the container and due to this and the `overflow: hidden` on parent, the shadow is invisible. While hovering on the image, the height and width of the pseudo-element is slowly transitioned to 0px and this makes the box shadow become visible (and thus ends up displaying a transparent overlay).

The `translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%)` transform effect is used to position the pseudo element at the center-mid point of the container element.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/1);
  overflow: hidden;
}
div:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 200px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transition: all 1s;
}
div:hover:after {
  height: 0%;
  width: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class='shadow-circle'></div>
```